# How to apply a list of modifciations on a scalaz State Monad without for comprehension

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, state-monad

I am currently playing arround with the scalaz State Monad. I want to implement a processing pipeline where a dynamic number of modifications will be applied to an initial State. I want to get out a final State after all processings have been done.

Here is a better graphical example.

```
                       +-------+        +-------+        +-------+
                       |       |        |       |        |       |
Initial State  +-----> |   m1  | +----> |   m2  | +----> |   m3  | +----> Final State
                       |       |        |       |        |       |
                       +-------+        +-------+        +-------+
```

I came up with this code

```
import  scalaz._
import  Scalaz._

object Main2 {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val m1 = State[String, Unit] { (x:String) =>(x + " " + x, () )}
    val m2 = State[String, Unit] { (x:String) =>(x.toUpperCase(), () )}
    val m3 = State[String, Unit] { (x:String) =>(x.toLowerCase(), () )}

    val finalState = for(
      _ <- m1;
      _ <- m2;
      f <- m3
    ) yield (f)

    println( finalState.run("Foo") )

  }

}
```

This works so far but i dont know the exact number of modiffications at compile time so i can not use a for comprehension.

What i need is this

```
import  scalaz._
import  Scalaz._

object Main2 {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val m1 = State[String, Unit] { (x:String) =>(x + " " + x, () )}
    val m2 = State[String, Unit] { (x:String) =>(x.toUpperCase(), () )}
    val m3 = State[String, Unit] { (x:String) =>(x.toLowerCase(), () )}

    type MyState = State[String, Unit];

    val modifications = List[MyState](m1,m2,m3);

    modifications.???.run("Foo")

  }

}
```

1. How can apply this list of stateful computations on my initial state **Foo** so it has the same effect as i would use a for comprehension ?
2. How can i combine this with the use of error handling in a **fail fast** approach?

Would this be a better signature for my modifications in terms of error handling ?

```
 type ModificationType = StateT[Try, String, Unit]
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the easy way is something like

```
modifications.reduceLeft((a: MyState, b:MyState) => a.flatMap(_ => b));
```

which is essentially a rewrite of the for comprehension.

It looks like scalaz also provides `sequenceU` which could also be used

```
modifications.sequenceU
```

but I'm not sure about that one. (I don't have scala compiler with me)

For your second question, yes, that should provide you with what you need.